# Can I pattern match with a function defined in a where clause?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, binary-tree, where-clause, subtree

My goal is to define a function "proper" which takes in a "Tree a" Datatype:

```
data Tree a = One a | Two (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

and produces all proper subtrees (i.e. all subtrees except itself) with a recursive definition.

My current code looks like this:

```
proper :: Tree a -> [Tree a]
proper (One a) = []
proper (Two t1 t2) = [t1,t2] ++ proper' t1 ++ proper' t2
proper' (One a) = [One a]
proper' (Two t1 t2) = [t1,t2] ++ proper' t1 ++ proper' t2
```

and I was wondering whether there is any way to get `proper'` in a where clause instead. I have tried using standard pattern matching and case expressions but both lead to parser errors.

Note: there is a previous function I made called subs which produces all subtrees of the tree including itself but I am not allowed to use this in my definition of `proper`

edit: I solved it without having to define a new function anyway, but the where clause should work I must have messed it up in the script. Working code now:

```
proper :: Tree a -> [Tree a]
proper (One a) = []
proper (Two t1 t2) = [t1,t2] ++ proper t1 ++ proper t2
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried that didn't work?  It really looks like you should be able to just write `where` and then define `proper'`.

Comment: never mind I didn't even have to do it the way that I did, although I did try the where clause and it worked so I must have done something wrong the first time.

Comment: Just a reminder that you can answer your own questions, that way it won't show up as unsolved the next time someone searches for this :)

Comment: @dranjohn ah that's good to know thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
proper :: Tree a -> [Tree a]
proper (One a) = []
proper (Two t1 t2) = [t1,t2] ++ proper' t1 ++ proper' t2
  where
    proper' (One a) = [One a]
    proper' (Two t1 t2) = [t1,t2] ++ proper' t1 ++ proper' t2
```

However I don't see for what you need `proper'` as this code works as well (and in contrary to yours doesn't duplicate the leaves):

```
proper :: Tree a -> [Tree a]
proper (One a) = []
proper (Two t1 t2) = [t1,t2] ++ proper t1 ++ proper t2
```

Comment: Yup, at first my code didn't acknowledge that an input of (One a) should be empty so I added the extra code without thinking I could  in fact simplify it. Thanks!